# Changing APR-embedded values returned by apr-1-config?

Tags: apr

Is it possible to modify APR's embedded values without recompiling APR? Or is there a way to edit and "reload" APR's configuration files?

On OS X 10.8 there are several bad values embedded in the Apache Portable Runtime Library. These values are causing problems compiling software whose makefiles rely on APR derived values.

Specifically, the values for `CC` reported by both `apr-1-config` and `apxs` point to a non-existent Xcode Toolchain (`OSX10.8.xctoolchain` instead of `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`). It would also be nice to tell `apxs` to use a different version of `libtool`.

The values seem to be pulling from some mix of `/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/apr_rules.mk` and `/usr/share/httpd/build/config_vars.mk`.
Editing `config_vars.mk` will change the results of queries to `apxs` but will not affect output from `apr-1-config`. I changed the `LIBTOOL` definition in config_vars.mk to point to /usr/bin/ and got this:

```
$ apxs -q LIBTOOL
/usr/bin/libtool --silent   // modified

$ apr-1-config --apr-libtool
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool  // default value
```

Neither `apxs` or `apr-1-config` reflected similar changes to `apr_rules.mk`. Unfortunately, I suspect my problem is with the values returned by `apr-1-config`.

**More:**

A simple workaround is to just symlink the xctoolchain as described here:  [Homebrew Issue #13586](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13586)

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain
```